# Error en Cors Laravel y Quasar

Tags: php, laravel, api, cors, quasar

tengo un problema con una petición a una API, estoy usando en backend Laravel y para Frontend Quasar, el error me indica lo siguiente: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya he intentado de todo lo que hay en internet, videos, configure de la siguiente manera mi Cors.php:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    return $next($request)

    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    ->header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS")
    ->header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
}
```

}

Para las rutas en api.php, lo mande a llamar de la siguiente manera: `Route::group(['middleware' => ['cors']], function () { });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yo tambien pase por ese problema, te cuento como lo solucione.

En realidad use dos estrategias, la primera :

Cree un `middleware` para los headers

Recuerda que un `middleware` nos permite gestionar las peticiones HTTP

```
php artisan make:middleware Cors
```

En el middleware

```
<?php
  namespace App\Http\Middleware;
  use Closure;
  class Cors
  {
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
      //Basicamente con esto configura que origenes, y que peticiones son aceptadas
      
      return $next($request)
      //Url a la que se le dará acceso en las peticiones, puedes poner un  "*" para aceptar todas los origenes
      ->header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://urlfronted.example")
      //Métodos que a los que se da acceso, agregas los que necesites 
      ->header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE")
      //Headers de la petición
      ->header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Token-Auth, Authorization"); 
    }
 }
```

Debes incluirlo en el archivo `Kernel.php`

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        //Aca hay muchos mas middlewares
        "cors" => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
    ];
```

Y dentro de tus rutas de api, `api.php`

Debes declarar todos tus endpoints dentro de la siguiente forma:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['cors']], function () {
     //Aca declaras tus rutas
     Route::get('Ejemplo', [EjemploController::class, 'functionExample']);
}]);
```

Tambien modifique el archivo de congiguraciones de cors que esta en la carpeta congig, llamado `cors.php`
Quedo de la siguiente forma:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
    | or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
    | in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
    |
    | To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
    |
    */
    'paths' => [
        'api/*', 
        'admin/api/*', 
        'sanctum/csrf-cookie'
    ],
    'allowed_methods' => [ //'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS'
        'GET', 
        'POST', 
        'PUT', 
        'PATCH',
        'OPTIONS'
    ],
    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
    'allowed_headers' => [//  'Content-Type, Authorization, Accept'
        'Content-Type', 
        'Authorization', 
        'Accept'
    ],
    'exposed_headers' => [],
    'max_age' => 0,
    'supports_credentials' => true,
];
```

sin embargo, tambien instale una extension de google chrome para configurar los origenes cruzados (cors)
Te la dejo en el siguiente enlace : [Herramienta para configurar cors](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-origin-cors-change/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc?hl=es)

**Pero eso no es todo**, como estoy usando React, uso `Axios` para hacer las peticiones, me aseguro de que todas mis peticiones contengan los parametros en el header para evitar errores de origen cruzado (cors) de la siguente forma:

```
return await axios({
                url:url,
                method:method,
                data:data,
                headers: {
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE',
                    "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*",
                    "access-control-allow-headers":"X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Token-Auth, Authorization"
                }
            })
            .then(function(res) { 
                return res
                
            })
            .catch(err => {return "el error es" +err})
```

[aca](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=es) te dejo otra extension de crhome para gestionar y testear cors

Bueno esta fue la forma que me sirvio a mi para solucionar los problemas de origenes cruzados, la verdad que fue algo realmente tedioso porque tambien probe de muchas formas y ninguna me funcionaba, espero a ti te funcione tambien.

**Por ultimo** en caso de que no te funcione [Aca hay un repositorio](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors) con recursos para gestionar el cors (este no alcance a probarlo porque lo de arriba me funciono)

Y lo mas importante la [Documentacion de control de acceso de origenes cruzados](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: Hola amigo, me funciono perfectamente, muchas gracias, otra cosa cuando compilo el proyecto, me aparece lo siguiente: WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:5500//ws' failed: eso en el navegador, estuve buscando el archivo pero no está en mi proyecto.

Comment: un gusto poder ayudar, para eso tienes que formular otra pregunta para agregar mayores antecedentes